# Why scanf is behaving weird for char input?

Tags: c, linux

```
/* Write macro for the following : 

1. Arithmetic Mean of two no.
2. Absolute value of a no.
3. To convert a Uppercase letter to lower case.
4. To obtain bigger of two numbers.

*/

#include<stdio.h>

#define am(a,b) ((a+b)/2)
#define abs(a) (a>=0?a:-a)
#define ul(ch) (ch>=65 && ch<=96 ? ch+32 : ch)
#define bigger(a,b) (a>=b?a:b)

int main () {

    int x,y;
    char c;

    printf("\nEnter two numbers:");
            scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);

    printf("\nThe arithmetic mean of two numbers is %f",(float)am(x,y));

    printf("\nEnter the number:");
            scanf("%d",&x);

    printf("\nThe absolute value of the number is %d",abs(x));

    printf("\nEnter the character:");
            scanf("%c",&c);

    printf("\nThe letter in lower case  is %c",ul(c));

    printf("\nEnter two numbers:");
            scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);

    printf("\nThe bigger of two numbers is %d",bigger(x,y));


 return 0;

 }
```

Everything is working fine except that program does not stop for taking character input.

Here is the snapshot of the output ....

```
  Enter two numbers:4
  5
  The arithmetic mean of two numbers is 4.000000

  Enter the number:-7   **/*After hitting enter here it reaches line no. 7 */** 
  The absolute value of the number is 7

  Enter the character:                                          
  The letter in lower case  is  

  Enter two numbers:4   **/*line no. 7*/**
  6

  The bigger of two numbers is 6
```

Comment: This is homework right? Please tag it.

Comment: (unrelated) `#define am(a,b) ((a+b)/2)` should be `#define am(a,b) ((a+b)/2.0)` to work as expected.

Comment: @Joe: It should actually be `#define am(a,b) (((a)+(b))/2.0)`, and the other macros should also have their parameters parenthesized as well.

Comment: It's usually better to avoid `scanf` entirely. http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that your scanf("%c",&c) is grabbing the carriage return entered when you hit enter to put in the -7.

Put a getchar (or another scanf("%c",&c)) right before the scanf and you shouldn't have that problem.

Comment: thanks ...... but it means whenever I will try to take as an input a charcter I need to put a  getchar() before

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, if there was another scanf before that caused the user to hit enter.

Comment: so we can say this is a drawback in c or is there any other method suggested ?????

Comment: Oh, according to http://employees.oneonta.edu/zhangs/CSCI109/scanfprintf.htm you can use scanf("\n%c", &x);  The \n before the %c causes the scanf to ignore the first \n.  I haven't tried it, but it would look nicer if it works nicely.

Answer (score 3):

It is because the %d skips white space, but %c does not -- or in other words.

The %d will skip any proceeding white space in your input stream, and the input pointer will be then just after the last digit -- which is most likely you newline.   So when you come to ask for the %c you will actually already have input data -- that is your newline -- and that is what you will read.

change your scanf to ask it to skip white space by just inserting a space before the %c, so

```
   scanf(" %c",&c);
```

Comment: but what's the solution I have to hit enter in order to reach the new line

Answer (score 1):

%c reads any character including whitescape, so it will "eat" the newline character.

Use: `scanf(" %c",&c);`

Answer (score 0):

That's because after your first `scanf`, the <kbd>enter</kbd> key is still in the input buffer, and the next `scanf` will store the <kbd>enter</kbd> value in `x`. Then your next `printf` will print it - effectively moving to a new line.

To fix this you can just add a `getchar()` call after each `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

A common issue with scanf is that it doesn't consume the newline caused by pressing enter. I usually get around it by using the following macro after a call to `scanf`

```
#define consumeBuffer() while (getchar() != '\n');
```

Of course this is not always what you want, but for most cases it will do the trick.