# Problem when I print a result of integer operation with chars in C

Tags: c

I state that I'm a newbie of C programming. I have to solve this "easy" C exercise.
The program has in input two chars. These chars must be a numeric value between 0 and 9. I have to sum the chars and print the result. I have to repeat this until the first inserted char isn't -1. This is my implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ASCII_ZERO 48
int main() {
    char a, b;
    while (1) {
        scanf("%c %c", &a, &b);
        int x = (int)a - ASCII_ZERO;
        int y = (int)b - ASCII_ZERO;
        if (x == -1) break;
        int z = x + y;
        char ris = z;
        printf("ris: %d\n", ris);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

When I run this code, I got this:

```
1 2
ris: 3
3 4
ris: -35
ris: -12
```

Why I get "ris" two times when I insert 3 and 4?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099209/why-scanf-is-behaving-weird-for-char-input

Comment: The `ASCII_ZERO` stuff is unncessary. You can replace with `'0'`. That is portable. Check `isdigit` to see if you have a number or otherwise. The issue you have is that when reading `char`s from standard input, is that you will have to skip over `'\n'` that remains on the stream.

Comment: On 2nd iteration with `scanf("%c %c", &a, &b);`, `a` is `'\n'`.

Comment: SImplest is change format to `" %c %c"` to skip spaces and newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
... 
      char a, b, c;    
      while (1) {    
          scanf("%c %c%c", &a, &b, &c);    
          ...
          printf("ris: %d\n", ris);    
      }    
      return 0;    
  }
```

I will not comment on code. But what is happening is that a is reading '\n' when the loop runs again : which you have pressed. As you are reading characters, '\n' and white spaces are also read. I just read `\n` into  a dummy variable `c` which is not used.

All this said, I suggest that you use `fgets`